# SQL - select max date for same article but different type

Tags: sql, date, max

I have the following query that has to show this table:

```
+-------------+------------+------------+----------+
|WRIN         |DESC        |TYPE        |DATE      |
+-------------+------------+------------+----------+
|10000-000-000|BLACK PEPPER|PQL Articles|13/02/2012|
+-------------+------------+------------+----------+
|10000-001-000|SALT        |PQL Articles|25/01/2010|
+-------------+------------+------------+----------+
```

But gives this instead  :

```
+-------------+------------+------------+----------+
|WRIN         |DESC        |TYPE        |DATE      |
+-------------+------------+------------+----------+
|10000-000-000|BLACK PEPPER|PQL Articles|13/02/2012|
+-------------+------------+------------+----------+
|10000-000-000|BLACK PEPPER|PQL Articles|17/08/2010|
+-------------+------------+------------+----------+
|10000-000-000|BLACK PEPPER|PQL Articles|25/01/2010|
+-------------+------------+------------+----------+
|10000-000-000|BLACK PEPPER|NO MARK UP  |04/06/2009|
+-------------+------------+------------+----------+
|10000-001-000|SALT        |PQL Articles|25/01/2010|
+-------------+------------+------------+----------+
|10000-001-000|SALT        |NO MARK UP  |15/07/2009|
+-------------+------------+------------+----------+
```

I have simplified the query because of names and other non-significant columns:

```
SELECT Format(adfc.[arti-cd-base], "00000") & "-" & 
              Format(pub_adfc.[arti-cd-sfx], "000") & "-" & 
              Format(pub_adfc.[adfc-cd-diffco], "000") AS Wrin, 
       pub_adfc.[adfc-desc]                            AS Description, 
       pub_arco.[arco-desc], 
       Max(pub_arcp.[arcp-dt-act])                     AS [MaxVanarcp-dt-act] 
FROM   (pub_arcp 
        INNER JOIN pub_arco 
                ON pub_arcp.[arco-nr] = pub_arco.[arco-nr]) 
       INNER JOIN pub_adfc 
               ON ( pub_arcp.[adfc-cd-diffco] = pub_adfc.[adfc-cd-diffco] ) 
                  AND ( pub_arcp.[arti-cd-base] = pub_adfc.[arti-cd-base] ) 
                  AND ( pub_arcp.[arti-cd-sfx] = pub_adfc.[arti-cd-sfx] ) 
GROUP  BY Format(pub_adfc.[arti-cd-base], "00000") & "-" & 
                    Format(pub_adfc.[arti-cd-sfx], "000") & "-" & 
                    Format(pub_adfc.[adfc-cd-diffco], "000"), 
          pub_adfc.[adfc-desc], 
          pub_arco.[arco-desc], 
          pub_arcp.[arcp-dt-act], 
          pub_adfc.[busi-id] 
HAVING (( ( pub_adfc.[busi-id] ) = "lpq" )) 
ORDER  BY Format(pub_adfc.[arti-cd-base], "00000") & "-" & 
                    Format(pub_adfc.[arti-cd-sfx], "000") & "-" & 
                    Format(pub_adfc.[adfc-cd-diffco], "000"), 
          pub_arcp.[arcp-dt-act] DESC;
```

I have tried things with TOP 1, Max(arcp-dt-act) but nothing works so far.

Does anybody have any idea how to get first table from this query?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE 1:

@Daniel B

Yes, 1 row for WRIN/DESC for the most recent date and therefore also the type that belongs to the most recent date.

@PeterRing

Yes, exactly like this. But I'm still figuring out how to do this.

For now I just removed the DATE-column and the GROUP BY and ORDER BY for [arcp-dt-act] (DATE) and in the select I used Last(pub_arco.[arco-desc]) instead of pub_arco.[arco-desc] and this seems to give only 1 article and with the right type (the type from the most recent date)

BTW: The DATE being shown in the query is not important, WRIN, DESC and TYPE is. I just needed the most recent type so therefore I needed the most recent date but Last() seems to do it.

Update 2:

@Daniel B

The query is being used in an Access Database 2010 if that is what you mean?

Comment: Do you want one row per WRIN/DESC? If so, what TYPE/DATE should be returned for WRIN/DESC combinations with multiple types and dates?

Comment: The problem is the group by. If i understand your point corectly, you would like to get back for every Desc, the maximum date, type, and wrin. In this case, you need to calculate the max date for every Desc in a subquery. Then inner join them back to your main query.

Comment: What database system are you using? This problem is best solved using non-standard SQL which is different in different databases.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (WRIN, DESC, TYPE)
  *
FROM (
  //your query here
) as subq
ORDER BY WRIN, DESC, TYPE, DATE DESC
```

Or without "type" if you don't need it.